# SQLite; InsteadOf update trigger; get number of affected records back

Tags: sqlite, triggers, sql-update, sql-view

According to https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_count_changes this pragma should not anymore be used in new projects.

How can I reliably return from within the SQLite insteadOf update trigger to the app (which executed the update command which triggered this trigger), how many records were affected by it?

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: Thx @shawn. That's what makes then the whole cool feature of InsteadOf triggers within SQLite more or less unusable. Because some EFs require the number of changed records to verify if the operation really worked. I am not even able to send any number back (e.g. by using a Select 1 statement at the end of the trigger.). Really incomplete implementation.